# Port Forwarding when using a Bridge and IPTables

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi that I am using as a bridge to allow it to act as a router to devices attached to it either via a physical port (`eth0`) or a wireless connection (`wlan0`). The Raspberry Pi has a 4G USB Dongle attached to it (`eth1`) and that is where internet traffic is being routed to.

I want to allow traffic on ports 80, 443, 22, and 23 to come through `eth1` and connect to services on the Raspberry Pi via IPTables. Is this possible, and if so, what configuration do I need to specify?

My current IPTables rules are:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have forwarding turned on it the `/etc/sysctl.conf` using `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.